# Verilog d-flipflop asynchronous reset metastability

Tags: asynchronous, verilog

I'm trying to understand the following Verilog code for D-FlipFlop with asynchronous reset:

```
module dff ( input d, input rstn, input clk, output reg q);
    always @ (posedge clk or negedge rstn)
       if (!rstn) q <= 0;
       else q <= d;
endmodule
```

I think at the negative edge of `rstn`, the value of `rstn` is unstable. It can be `0` or `1` or `x`. Then why can we use this unstable value in the next line of code `if (!rstn)`?

Comment: are you talking about reset synchronization?

Comment: Verilog describes *desired* behavior. At negedge of rstn the code wants the value of `q` to be **stable 0** therefore it has this statement: `if(!rstn) q<=0;` This is up to the synthesis tools to figure out timing in presence of metastability.

Comment: @m4j0rt0m hi, normally I would prefer a synchronous design, but I see this asynchronous code pattern so often, and just want to know why it works. So, on the verilog level, I don't want some code for an explicit reset synchronization. Though I'm not sure whether the synthesized circuit will automatically implement reset synchronization.

Comment: @Serge hi, thanks for the comment. By **"the code wants the value of q to be stable 0"**, do you mean that it's part of verilog grammar that when we specify `negedge reset` in the `always` block, then the `reset` value is automatically **stable 0**, and when we specify `posedge reset` it's **stable 1**?

Comment: In behavioral verilog there is no way to express unstable values. They are either known 0 and 1, unknown 'x' and high impedance 'z'.  Nothing else is available. Any change is represented by an edge, negative or positive. That is it. The simulation is completely digital on those values. negedge means switching from any of states to '0' and posege is switching from any of others states to '1'. There is no metastability in there.

Comment: @Serge thanks, now I understand that it's completely digital and has not metastability. What still confuses me is that in `if (!rstn) q<=0` we assume `rstn=0`, using the `rstn` value right **after** the edge. But in `else q<=d`, we use the `d` value right **before** the edge. This seems to be inconsistent.

Comment: all happens after one of the edges (posedge clk or nedgedg rstn). 'rstn' is 0  after its negedge. It can also stay 0 after clk posedge. If it is 0, no matter when,  then the output value 'q' goes to '0'. If rstn is '1', the input 'd' gets propagated to q at posedge of clk. The fact that this code reacts to the negedge of rstn makes it asynchronous (relating to clk). if you remove negedge it will become synchronous, only chaging values at posedge of clk.

Comment: @Serge thanks, I think I now understand that in behavioral verilog, I should not think about the timing details too much. With `negedge rstn` the value of `rstn` should just go to `0` instantaneously, and the next `if (~rstn)` is somehow "executed" after that, so it sees `rstn=0`.